# Android - How to show alert dialog inside linearlayout in a Layout file?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have a linearlayout in a layout file. I need to show alertdialog inside that linearlayout. How can i achieve this?

I tried this but it doesn't work correctly

```
llChartPopup.getLocationInWindow(chartPositions)//llChartPopup is sub linearlayout inside my layout file
        var viewGroup = findViewById<ContentFrameLayout>(android.R.id.content)
        var dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.pass_sa_chart_popup, viewGroup, false)
        var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setView(dialogView)

        alertDialog = builder.create()
        alertDialog.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
        alertDialog.window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
        var wmlp = alertDialog.window.attributes
        wmlp.x = chartPositions[0]
        wmlp.y = chartPositions[1]

        alertDialog.show()
```

Comment: alertDialog needs to be set some things before creating... so just create it after setting gravity, not at the beginning....

Answer (score 0):

```
 val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                val customView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null)
                 //Your views inside dialog
                val btnClose = customView.yourView
                alertDialog.setView(customView)
                val customDialog = alertDialog.create()
                customDialog.show()
```